# Make expanable search fit in space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I am trying to add an expandable search box to a row of items. I'm using the example [here](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/expanding-search-button-in-css) as the core of this. Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/3dqg97r7/2/). I tried to simulate the problem by limiting the widths. All of the style statements are just for formatting it here. The main problem is that I want to give the search `div` just enough room to display a search icon. And then, when it's moused over, it should expand to allow input. As you can see, it expands but in the wrong direction.

The original code had "float: right !important;" instead of the "position:fixed !important; z-index:100;" I changed it to. I did that thinking I could control the placement. And it worked, sort of. But the result isn't what I want.

In short, the code as provided by the source site works correctly but only when the search icon is on a line by itself. Can it be placed on a line with other elements and still expand as needed?

Here's the code I am using:

```
    <style>
     .search-form .form-group {
      position:fixed !important;
      z-insex:100;
      transition: all 0.35s, border-radius 0s;
      width: 32px;
      height: 32px;
      background-color: #fff;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
      border-radius: 25px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    .search-form .form-group input.form-control {
      padding-right: 20px;
      border: 0 none;
      background: transparent;
      box-shadow: none;
      display:block;
    }
    .search-form .form-group input.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      display: none;
    }
    .search-form .form-group input.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
      /* Firefox 18- */
      display: none;
    }
    .search-form .form-group input.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
      /* Firefox 19+ */
      display: none;
    }
    .search-form .form-group input.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
      display: none;
    }
    .search-form .form-group:hover,
    .search-form .form-group.hover {
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 4px 25px 25px 4px;
    }
    .search-form .form-group span.form-control-feedback {
      position: absolute;
      top: -1px;
      right: -2px;
      z-index: 2;
      display: block;
      width: 34px;
      height: 34px;
      line-height: 34px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #3596e0;
      left: initial;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    </style> 


    <div style="width:250px;border:1px solid">
      <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px;border:1px solid;"><img src="example.com/test.png" width="100"></div>
      <div style="display:inline-block;width:80px;border:1px solid;vertical-align:top;">A block of text</div>
      <div class="search" style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
        <div class="searchbox-margin">
          <form action="" class="search-form">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
              <label for="search" class="sr-only">Search</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywords" id="search" placeholder="Search">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div> 
          </form>  
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```css
.search-form .form-group input.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      display: none;
    }
    .search-form .form-group input.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
      /* Firefox 18- */
      display: none;
    }
    .search-form .form-group input.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
      /* Firefox 19+ */
      display: none;
    }
    .search-form .form-group input.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
      display: none;
    }
    .search-form .form-group:hover,
    .search-form .form-group.hover {
      width: 50%;
      border-radius: 4px 25px 25px 4px;
      /*transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;*/
    }
    .search-form .form-group span.form-control-feedback {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    right: -2px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 34px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #3596e0;
    left: initial;
    font-size: 14px;
}

    .search-form .form-group input.form-control {
    border: 0 none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: block;
    height: 27px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    width: 87%;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background: transparent;
}

.search-form .form-group {
    position: fixed !important;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: all 0.35s, border-radius 0s;
    width: 48px;
    height: 32px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-top:2px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:250px;border:1px solid">
      <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px;border:1px solid;"><img src="example.com/test.png" width="100"></div>
      <div style="display:inline-block;width:80px;border:1px solid;vertical-align:top;">A block of text</div>
      <div class="search" style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
        <div class="searchbox-margin">
          <form action="" class="search-form">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywords" id="search" placeholder="Search">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div> 
          </form>  
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that but it does about the same thing. If you think of the 250 px border in the example as the full window,  then the search button will be at the right end of the window. So when it is moused over, the box expands to a hidden area. if it expanded to the left, I think it will do what I want. What controls the direction it expands in?